# What does $f(5x)$ mean when I differentiate?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

if 
$$f(5x)=x^2 + x$$

$$f '(2) = ?$$

Answer is **9/25**

But I do not know how it came

How i can factor or simplify **$$f(5x)$$**
but i want understand what **f(5x)** mean?

Comment: chain rule :$5f'(5x)=2x+1$ put $x=2/5$. here

Comment: Firstly, you need $f(y) = y^2/25 + y/5$.

Comment: that's wrong the answer is 9/25 when x=2
i want know how !

Comment: I think the point here is finding $f'(2)$ without finding a general formula for $f(y)$.

Comment: @johnwick But we just left you $2$ answers below.

Comment: @Rebellos i will see you answer

Comment: @johnwick Sorry, I find that daulomb's method is correct. Please double check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The derivative of the expression $f(g(x))$ is given as :

$$[f(g(x))]'=f'(g(x))\cdot g(x)$$

supposing that $f,g$ are differentiable functions.

This means that :

$$[f(5x)]'=f'(5x)\cdot (5x)'=5f'(5x)$$

which means, taking the derivative on both sides of $f(5x) = x^2 + x$, you'll get :

$$[f(5x)]'=\frac{2}{5}x+\frac{1}{5}$$

Now, just setting $x=2/5$, you'll yield your result for $f'(2) = 9/25$.

This is important to know (the chain rule) because such differentation issues occur often.

Alternatively, you could just let $t=5x$ and substitute and calculate from there on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. [+1] Yet, when setting $x = 2/5$, you still assume there is a $y = 5x$ in your mind.

Comment: @Ryan Sure I do, yes. Better not to say that $y=5x$ by the way, since $y=f(x)$ in the cartesian coordinates system. Let's say that in order to get the number $2$ from the expression $5x$ you'd need $x=2/5$. Alternatively, it just follows from letting $t=5x$ and substituting.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Using $y$ is indeed confusing. Thanks :-)

Comment: @johnwick I have edited Rebellos' answer, and please wait it for peer review.

Comment: @Ryan okay .. also i have edited my question to be more clear

Comment: @Ryan Sorry for rejecting your edit.  I didn't see the comments during the review.

Comment: @GNUSupporter No worries :-)

Comment: I don't why my eyes saw a random function but thanks for the edit/correction !

Answer (score 1):

Setting $$t=5x$$ then we get
$$f(t)=\left(\frac{t}{5}\right)^2+\frac{t}{5}$$
then we get $$f'(t)=...$$

Comment: yes Dr this is the correct answer thx
but why we setting t = 5x ?

Comment: @johnwick This is probably because you need $5x = 2$ and $2$ can be regarded as $t = 2$.

Comment: @Ryan but i want (5x)' =2 Is there a difference

Comment: @johnwick $(5x)' = 5$ and it cannot be $2$.

Comment: @johnwick You do **not** want $5x=2$, you want $f'(5x) \to f'(2)$ which means $5x=2 \Leftrightarrow x = 2/5$